# How to declare ULARGE_INTEGER in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, declare, unsigned-integer

Based upon this question [How to declarate LARGE_INTEGER in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683491/how-to-declarate-large-integer-in-c) with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683491/how-to-declarate-large-integer-in-c/683810#683810) of:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Absolute, Size=8)]
struct LARGE_INTEGER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]public Int64 QuadPart;
    [FieldOffset(0)]public UInt32 LowPart;
    [FieldOffset(4)]public Int32 HighPart;
}
```

Is my assumption below for declaring [`ULARGE_INTEGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383742%28VS.85%29.aspx) correct?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
public struct ULARGE_INTEGER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt64 QuadPart;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 LowPart;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public UInt32 HighPart;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply an ulong in C#, no need to jump through the LayoutKind.Explicit hoop.  The union was necessary because C and C++ compilers didn't have a native 64-bit type in the olden days.

Comment: So just swap out all declarations for `UInt64` (`ulong`) and it should be ok?

Comment: Just completely forget about the structure declaration.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'm ditching `LARGE_INTEGER` for `Int64` too.